# is standard my parsing approach?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I want to write a simple compiler.
in its grammer each line contains (just) a statement.

1) first the scanner does his job; so for each line we have tokens.

2) for each line we check its type(if stm, for stm, var defintion, end, ...).
In this step there is lines that they types are diagnosed. for example:

```
func definition
var def
assignment
for stm
...
end
end
```

3) and now it is time to check lines order.

In other word we check:

1) each word alone (scanner)

2) each line alone (line grammer)

3) block of lines (programming language grammer)

My question:
The parse step is 2? or 3? or 2 & 3?
and i think it is not a standard approach for a parser. if i think right, what is wrong? and what is the solution?

Comment: What language are you parsing? Does that language require exactly one statement/declaration/whatever per line? If so, parsing it a line at a time (like old-style BASIC) might make sense.

Comment: yes! exacltly one statement per line.

Comment: You still have two distinct grammars, one for lines and one for blocks of lines. It would probably make more sense to define a single grammar, and to treat end-of-line as a token in that grammar.

Comment: Take a look at coursera prof. Aiken's compilers course, it is not difficult to understand and you will get a good grasp of this basics. Andrew Appel's book is also a "gentle introduction".

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't standard, and it almost certainly won't work. For one thing, lines are insignificant in most programming languages. For another, order checking isn't an explicit phase. It's all part of grammar recognition. Far too broad to cover here. I suggest you read a good book.

Comment: of course my means of order is grammer. for example:
func -> begin stm end ; 
stm -> for | if | assignment | var_def

Comment: So why not say so? By using non-standard language you are already in non-standard land.